# Adding space and an increasing number each line

Tags: awk

I am trying to edit a text file and add a space, then an increasing number. I am trying to do this with awk, however the best result currently puts the counter on a new line. I've tried other examples but it's not quite working.

Input

```
line
line
```

Current

```
awk '{$1 = $1 NR; print }' input.txt > output.txt
```

Result

```
line
1
line
2
```

Intended

```
line 1
line 2
```

Also, putting this in a bash script currently gives a blank output

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '{$1 = $1 NR; print }' $1 > output.txt
```

Comment: if your input is `line\nline\n`, `awk '{$1 = $1 NR; print }'` prints `line1\nline2`. It doesn't create additional lines. You just need to explicitly add the space and probably want to use `$0` instead to put the number on the end of the line and not after the first field: `awk '{$0 = $0 " " NR; print }'`

Comment: Thanks, but actually I don't want new lines. The output I'm looking for is `line 1\nline 2`. Your code gives `line\n 1\nline\n 2` for me

Comment: Hmm. It shouldn't. What awk are you running? Can you [edit] your question to show what happens in full on a sample run? E.g. run `awk --version`, `cat input.txt` and `awk '{$0 = $0 " " NR; print }' input.txt` and just copypaste the whole lot, prompts and outputs.

Comment: do `dos2unix input.txt` first;

Comment: Thanks for help all, yes the problem was the input file being produced in windows etc. @ilkkachu your snippet worked.

Comment: @littlefield, hmm. carriage returns should just break the output, you'd get `line<CR>1<NL>`, which would look like `1ine` on output as the CR takes the cursor back. Unless of course you have an editor that also takes a lone CR as a line break.

Comment: @ilkkachu I'm not sure, but it became clear that was the problem when I did `head output.txt` and the first few characters of each line of the input was missing, though they were visible in the text editor. Lesson seems to be don't use Windows!

Comment: @littlefield, yep, not sure about Windows as such, but the CRs often cause a lot of confusion

Comment: See [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just using this approach

```
awk '{print $1,NR}'
```

Example

```
$ cat example.txt
line
line
$ awk '{print $1,NR}' example.txt
line 1
line 2
$
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is giving `line\n 1\n line\n 2` for me

Comment: Your input has CR+LF then, in which case you'd need to use something like `awk '{print substr($1,0,length($0)-1),NR}'`

Answer (score 0):

why not

```
awk '{printf "%s %d\n",$1,NR}' input.txt > output.txt
```

where

- `"%s %d\n"` will format first argument as a string (`%s`), next as a number (`%d`) and print a new line (`\n`)

Answer (score 0):

By change in record:

```
awk '$++NF=NR' input.txt
```

Comment: That would cause awk to replace all spaces in the input with single blank chars (so tabs would become blanks, pairs of blanks would become single blanks, etc.) and then rebuild the record, and it'd make awk have to evaluate a condition before printing instead of doing it unconditionally, all of which is inefficient and probably undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
k=open('file','r')
g=1
for i in k:
    print "{0} {1}".format(i.strip(),g)
    g=int(g)+1
```

output

```
python ko.py 
line 1
line 2



sed command

 sed -n '/.*/{;=;p}' file|sed "N;s/\n/ /g"| awk '{print $2,$1}'
line 1
line 2

using cat command

cat -n file| awk '{print $2,$1}'
line 1
line 2
```